# How Can I perform Django Multiple Filter on a Model

Tags: python, django

I am current working on a Django project where I want user to perform property search using different criterial like Property type, State, Minimum bedrooms, Bathroom type, minimum and max price. I want the search to be flexible such that the user chooses which field to search for and not forcing him to input every form field during search. I have tried my best but no error and no positive result, rather even when the user search matches the Model record, it still does not display it.
Here is my Model Code:

```
class Property(models.Model):
PROPERTY_TYPE_CHOICES = [
    ('Complete House', 'Complete House'),
    ('Apartment', 'Apartment'),
    ('Self-Contained', 'Self-Contained'),
   
    
]

BEDROOM_CHOICES = [
    ('1', '1'),
    ('2', '2'),
    ('3', '3'),
    ('4', '4'),
    ('5', '5+'),
]

BATHROOM_CHOICES = [
    ('Self-contained', 'Self-contained'),
    ('General', 'General'),
    ('Private Detached', 'Private Detached'),
]

COUNTRY_CHOICES = [
    ('Nigeria', 'Nigeria'),
    
]

STATE_CHOICES = [
    ('Abia', 'Abia'),
    ('Adamawa', 'Adamawa'),
    ('Akwa Ibom', 'Akwa Ibom'),
    ('Anambra ', 'Anambra '),
    ('Bauchi', 'Bauchi'),
    ('Bayelsa', 'Bayelsa'),
    ('Benue ', 'Benue '),
    ('Borno', 'Borno'),
    ('Cross River', 'Cross River'),
    ('Delta', 'Delta'),
    ('Ebonyi', 'Ebonyi'),
    ('Edo', 'Edo'),
    ('Ekiti', 'Ekiti'),
    ('Enugu', 'Enugu'),
    ('Gombe', 'Gombe'),
    ('Imo', 'Imo'),
    ('Jigawa', 'Jigawa'),
    ('Kaduna', 'Kaduna'),
     ('Kano', 'Kano'),
    ('Katsina', 'Katsina'),
    ('Kebbi', 'Kebbi'),
    ('Kogi', 'Kogi'),
    ('Kwara', 'Kwara'),
    ('Lagos', 'Lagos'),
    
]

agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
landlord = models.ForeignKey(Landlord, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
property_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PROPERTY_TYPE_CHOICES)
bedrooms = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True, choices=BEDROOM_CHOICES)
bathroom_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=BATHROOM_CHOICES)
country = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES)
state = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
state_lga = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
image = models.ImageField(default='avatar.jpg', blank=False, null=False, upload_to ='profile_images', 

)
last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.description
```

Form code:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
property_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Property.PROPERTY_TYPE_CHOICES, required=False)
state = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Property.STATE_CHOICES, required=False)
min_beds = forms.CharField(max_length=10, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "Min Bedrooms"}))
bathroom_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Property.BATHROOM_CHOICES, required=False)
min_price = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "Min Price"}))
max_price = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "Max Price"}))
```

View code:

```
# Home Page View.
def index(request):
    listings = Property.objects.filter(is_available=True).order_by('-last_updated')[:6]
form = SearchForm(request.GET or None)

if request.method == 'GET' and form.is_bound:
    if form.is_valid():
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
        property = cleaned_data.get('property_type')
        state = cleaned_data.get('state')
        min_beds = cleaned_data.get('min_beds') or 0
        bathroom = cleaned_data.get('bathroom_type')
        min_price = cleaned_data.get('min_price')
        max_price = cleaned_data.get('max_price')

        # Filter properties based on search parameters
        properties = Property.objects.filter(is_available=True)
        if property:
            properties = properties.filter(property_type=property)
        if state:
            properties = properties.filter(state=state)
        if min_beds:
            properties = properties.filter(bedrooms__gte=min_beds)
        if bathroom:
            properties = properties.filter(bathroom_type=bathroom)
        if min_price:
            properties = properties.filter(price__gte=min_price)
        if max_price:
            properties = properties.filter(price__lte=max_price)

        # Apply sorting
        properties = properties.order_by('-last_updated')[:6]

        context = {
            'listings': properties,
            'page_title': 'Ease to Locate Ease to Rent... | UyaProp',
            'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, 'pages/index.html', context)

context = {
    'listings': listings,
    'form': form,
}
return render(request, 'pages/index.html', context)
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="search-property">
        <form method="GET" action="{% url 'pages-index' %}">
           {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="single-search-property">
                       <div class="intro">
                          {{ form.property_type }}
                      </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="single-search-property">
                        <div class="intro">
                            {{ form.state }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="single-search-property">
                        {{ form.min_beds }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="single-search-property">
                       <div class="intro">
                          {{ form.bathroom_type }}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="single-search-property">
                        {{ form.min_price }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="single-search-property">
                        {{ form.max_price }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="single-search-property button">
                        <button type="submit">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very tedious way to archive search functionality, instead of writing manually search filter you use **`pip install django-filter`** library.

"Django-filter is a reusable Django application allowing users to declaratively add dynamic QuerySet filtering from URL parameters." link [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-filter/)

##### My github Repo link [here](https://github.com/Mahammadhusain/trip.git)

#### Browser Output

[image]